# Find integers $a, b, c, d, e$ and $f$ such that $P(X) = (aX^2 +bX +c)^2 −5X(eX +f)^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $$P(X) = X^{4} + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1$$

Find integers $a, b, c, d, e$ and $f$ such that $$P(X) = (aX^2 +bX +c)^2 −5X(eX +f)^2$$

I am absolutely horrible at math in general. My class just started and this is the first bit of homework, I could use some guidance to get started on this problem. Thank's for any tips, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Just expand and compare coefficients. Obviously $ a=1$

Comment: @N.S.JOHN could you give me an example of what expand and comparing coefficients is? I don't know what that is. Thanks!

Comment: $(ax+b)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$, then $a=b=1$ is Aam example

Comment: I don't understand... I took $(ax+b)^2$ and got $a^2b^2+2abx+b^2$ how did you get your equation? Why did you set a and b to 1?

Comment: Also, after expanding the equation fully, I don't understand how you compare coefficients. The $x^4$ is the only one by itself, i end up with $2abx^3$ from the $(ax^2+bx+c)^2$ and then theres $-5e^2x^3$ from the $-5x(ex+f)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest tip for this kind of thing is that you're trying to find ways such that it is true for *any* possible value of $X$, therefore you can work out what must be true by checking what happens with *specific* values of $X$.

For example, $P(0) = 0^4 + 0^3 + 0^2 + 0 + 1 = 1$, and $P(0) = c^2$. So clearly $c^2 = 1$, meaning that $c=\pm 1$. Then $P(1) = 5$ and $P(1) = (a+b+c)^2 - 5(e + f)$ which you can use to relate all the values together.

After a while, you'll be able to get some specific values in, at which point you might want to see if expanding things out will help. For example, you can see that in the second expression the coefficient of $X^4$ is just $a^2$, so $a = \pm 1$ too.

In general, you need at least $n$ equations to find a solution for $n$ unknowns, so try at least 5 different values of $X$ to substitute in.

EDIT: Since you've asked about comparing coefficients, here's a quick explanation:

You're trying to find values $a, b, c, d, e, f$ to make the two polynomials equivalent. The most obvious way to do that is to try to arrange the two of them so that they *look* similar, then compare the two to relate the various things to each other.

As an example, here's a simpler problem: given $T(x) = x^3 + 6x^2 + 12x + 25$, find values $a, b, c$ such that $T(x) = (ax + b)^3 + c$. We expand the second one, giving us $T(x) = a^3 x + 3a^2 b x^2 + 3a b^2 x + b^3 + c$. Then, we compare the coefficients of $x^3$, $x^2$, $x$ and $1$ (i.e. the constant coefficient).

First, by looking at the coefficients of $x^3$, we get $a^3 = 1$, so $a = 1$. Then, looking at the coefficients of $x^2$, we have $3a^2 b = 6$, so using our knowledge about $a$ we get $b = 2$. In this case, the coefficient of $x$ gives us no additional knowledge except that we haven't messed anything up. Finally, the constant terms give us $b^3 + c = 25$, and since $b^3 = 8$ we have $c = 17$.

Do you see how you could apply that to your problem? You just have to be careful expanding out the $(aX^2 + bX + c)^2$ term.

Comment: Don't you think this is slightly overkill? Comparing coefficients would do

Comment: Well in this case, comparing coefficients requires expanding a three-term quadratic, which is something I mess up 80% of the time. Also, it provides a useful trick for more complicated versions of the same problem.

Comment: So I came up with $$T(x) = (1x+2)^3 + 17$$. Just making sure I'm correct. I think I can extrapolate this to my original question, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: After following through your steps, with $a,c=+/- 1$, how do you decide whether to use the positive or negative 1 in the next equations? I don't understand how this helps with so many variables

Comment: So you're going to wind up with a bunch of relationships between the variables. That's when you have to try to eliminate the variables one at a time to get to expressions involving individual variables. However, I have a sneaking suspicion that this particular problem doesn't have any real solutions.

Comment: I've taken it as far as I can, I don't think it's possible to single out any variable besides the +/- 1 for a and c. Thanks for your help though. I'll just wait and see how this is supposed to be done when we get our assignments returned.

Comment: It's not easy, that's for sure. However, there is at least one set of integer solutions. Try the different possible combinations of values of a and c, and see if you can solve any of the resulting equations.

Comment: how do you decide whether to use the positive or negative $1$ for $a$ or $c$? 
Here's the expanded equation, I don't see any possible way of eliminating variables.
$$a^2x^4+2abx^3+2acx^2+b^2x^2+2bcx+c^2-5e^2x^3-10efx^2-5f^2x$$ I might stand a chance if there was no e or f, but with those mixed in I have no idea how to compare coefficients

Comment: There are four possibilities - a = c = 1, a = c = -1, and the two cases where they're unequal. Pick one, work through the resulting equations. Either you'll get a nice solution, an ugly solution, or no solution. Sometimes you might have to do another case of "see which of these two possible values results in a nicer answer". I couldn't find a nice way to get the answer other than exploring the various possibilities one by one.